# does arrays and input with scanf goes hand in hand?

Tags: c, arrays

What is wrong with the following code written in c language?
I encountered a segmentation fault. what is it?

```
int a[2];
for(i=0;i<2;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",a[i]);
    printf("%d",a[i]);
}
```

Why couldn't it run? leave about declarations. Does scanf have any delay problems?

Comment: Please don't use library functions like `scanf` and `printf` without knowing the basic usage of it. Read man page here http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf .

Comment: @VoidPointer That is very good comment but i ask you something else also. Yes, scanf requires pointer but what happens when it dont have is my question.And moreover i encountered a segmentation fault. what is that in this context?]

Comment: Mention this in question clearly. The arguments of `scanf` given after format specifier are considered and interpreted as **pointers**. The behavior is **undefined** when arguments other than pointer like value of integer `a[i]` are sent after first argument.

Comment: "scanf have any delay problems"!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
scanf("%d",a[i]);
```

is wrong. The `%d` format specifier requires *a  pointer* to where the value should be stored after conversion, i.e. it should be:

```
scanf("%d", &a[i]);
```

This is required since otherwise you pass the value of `a[i]` to `scanf()`, giving it no way to *change* the value. By passing the address of the value, `scanf()` can simply write to the provided memory address to change the value that is stored there. With `printf()`, you don't want your values to be changing, so passing them directly to `printf()` is fine.

Also, conversions (like many other forms of I/O) can fail, so you should check the return value before relying on the conversion having succeeded:

```
if( scanf("%d", &a[i]) == 1 )
  printf("%d\n", a[i]);
```

You should probably read [the manual page for `scanf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) a couple more times. :)

Comment: However it is not required in printf. Why is that? and please answer me what is segmentation fault?

Comment: @max I added some more text about `printf()`. You can [read up on segmentation faults](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) elsewhere. Basically it means your operating system detected that your program did something it's not allowed to do (like try to write to memory it doesn't own by interpreting the integer `a[i]` as a pointer).

Answer (score 1):

Pass the address of a[i] to scanf instead of the value of a[i].

```
scanf("%d",&a[i]);
```